# Symfony template referencing

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a Twig template in this folder structure

```
appName
   app
     resources
        FosUserBundle
                 views
                    myTemplate.html.twig
        views
          Form
            templateToRefer.html.twig
```

from -myTemplate.html.twig- I would like to reference               -templateToRefer.html.twig- that is inside folder views that is brother of FosUserBundle folder. Is there any way to do it?

My way is this

```
{% form_theme form 'Form/fields.html.twig' %}
```

but I always get error

```
Unable to find template "Form/fields.html.twig" (looked into: /home/felpone/Scrivania/appName/app/Resources/views
```

Comment: Folder names are case sensitive on linux, your folder is `resources` while you've configured twig to look in `Resources`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass the full path 'AppBundle:Form:templateToRefer.html.twig'

Comment: Tried but... Unable to find template "AppBundle:Form:templateToRefer.html.twig" (looked into: /home/felpone/Scrivania/appName/app/Resources/views,